# Why PyCharm not running the same code as run in shell?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, mxnet

I have a strange behavior today. When I am running my mxnet model load program in PyCharm it gives :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'dmlc::Error'
  what():  [14:21:09] /home/travis/build/dmlc/mxnet-distro/mxnet-build/3rdparty/mshadow/mshadow/./stream_gpu-inl.h:115: Check failed: err == CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS (1 vs. 0) : Create cublas handle failed
```

But the same code and same virtual-env activated running flawlessly!

What is happening in PyCharm? Is it changing as Env? Any ideas?

Comment: it might be running on a different virtual enviroment (you need to set that) it might also be running with the wrong parameters (you need to set the parameters too), I can't think of any other reason why it might not run the same as the console

Comment: I will check the ENV for all. Btw all parameters are same

Comment: and the `cwd`. Normally on terminal we go in the correct directory, to execute command, and we tend to forget that PyCharm may use a different one. In any case I'm surprised on such non-informative error message.

Answer (score 0):

It is ENV problem. Pycharm didn't recognize my .bashrc LD_LIBRARY_PATH this was the problem.